# How to licence my open-source game engine for proprietary game

Tags: open-source, licensing

I'm developing a puzzle game that's going to be based on my own game engine.
My intention is to make the game engine open-source (including some demos) while the game itself (levels, textures, level editor, ...) to be paid.
What's worrying me is what type of license for the game engine should I use?

I think this is similar to original DOOM source code re-release in 1999 under GPL licence. You can do whatever you want with it but if you want to play the original game you need the `DOOM.WAD` file which you can legaly obtain only by buying the original game.

So, can I use GPL? I think it means that all software build on top of it has to stay GPL. But maybe in my case it doesn't matter because I'm not going to make changes to the engine that wouldn't be also in the standalone game engine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IANAL**

The GPL only applies if you're linking non-GPL code with GPL code. Using the software does not affect your obligations to change your license (for example, code compiled with GCC doesn't have to be GPL).

I'd recommend doing one of the following:

- Dual-license game engine GPL and proprietary

  - give yourself proprietary license when packaging the game engine with the game itself
- License the game engine LGPL

  - can link your game engine into your game without open sourcing the game

If your "game" only consists of level packs and other resources (no code linked with game engine), the GPL is completely ok.

As author, you currently have all rights to the source. If you take someone else's code that they've copyrighted, you cannot relicense that code under a proprietary license.

Comment: The first one makes sence to me. I want to give the game engine for free but I'm a bit afraid that someone will just take it and try to sell as it is. So maybe I can use GPL and clearly state that I give everyone permission to use parts of it in their own proprietary games but still restrict using the engine as whole only under GPL.

Comment: This is probably what you're already thinking, but why not release part under LGPL (the part others can use in a proprietary game) and the rest GPL, assuming that the parts under LGPL are used as a library by you. Otherwise, you could consider using the [MPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Public_License) if the parts you want others to use are in individual files. Then others can use just those files, not the library as a whole, as is in a proprietary game.

Comment: Licensing libraries under LGPL and the core "game" that connects everything together under GPL is a good idea. That's probably the way I want to go but I'll have a look on MPL as well. Thanks @tjameson!